# SyntaxError: Unexpected key 'export' ([native code]:33)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

The error from the browser is not very descriptive, and I tried to research a solution without much luck.

I'm only getting the error whenever I add this line to the top of my component ToDo:
`import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';`

Please note that I am using scrimba, so I am not able to make changes to the manifest.json file, 
Also I tried to add babel, but I am not sure what to do with it after I added it. Here's the ToDo.js component file:

```
import React from 'react'

function ToDo(){
    return(
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <span> Placeholder text here</span>            
        </div>
    )
}
export default ToDo
```

Please help, I just wanted to add a fancier checkbox and now I'm stuck in a rabbit hole

Comment: can you share codesandbox link

Comment: @FahadMahmood oops I meant scrimba, here's the link so you can see what it looks like, but its basically just for teaching you how to code React and it allows you to pause and edit the code https://scrimba.com/p/p7P5Hd/cewQ3fp

Comment: you need to add material-ui as a project dependency

Comment: there is an option there to add dependency

Comment: @material-ui/core@4.9.13 this may work

Comment: @FahadMahmood I already added the latest material-ui/core as a dependency, do I have to add material-ui as well?

Comment: no, it should work like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figured out the answer!

It was not very intuitive, and didn't really mention it on the [Button API docs](https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/#button), but I just needed to update my React app version.

After a ton of digging I found out that, even though some features work, but for ALL the features of MaterialUI to work, the version of [React needed is 16.8](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/installation/#npm), and my React version was below that.

So I just needed to update the version of React on my app.